# Access SQL: Select all rows with same value if one value is contained

Tags: sql, ms-access

Say, I have a table looking like this

```
ID | TB | KNo | Values1 | ...
_________________________________
 1 | 301| 111 | 123     | ...
 2 | 302| 111 | 123     | ...
 3 | 303| 111 | 123     | ...
 4 | 302| 222 | 123     | ...
 5 | 303| 222 | 123     | ...
 6 | 301| 333 | 123     | ...
 7 | 301| 333 | 123     | ...
 8 | 302| 333 | 123     | ...
 9 | 302| 333 | 123     | ...
 10| 303| 333 | 123     | ...
 11| 303| 333 | 123     | ...
```

I only want to take these rows, that have the same KNo but only if one of the TB = 301. So in this case I only want rows 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 because they have the same KNo and among those rows with the same KNo there is at least one row with TB = 301.
I do not want rows 4 and 5 even though because none of the rows have TB = 301.

Is there a pretty SQL query that will do this?

Answer (score 3):

There are different solutions. For example using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM tab t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tab t2 WHERE t1.KNo = t2.KNo AND t2.TB = 301)
```

or `IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM tab t1
WHERE t1.KNo IN(SELECT t2KNo FROM tab t2 WHERE t2.TB = 301)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it with a join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT KNo
 FROM table t2
 WHERE t2.TB = 301) t2
ON t1.KNo = t2.KNo
ORDER BY t1.ID
```

So basically you write a sub-query to find the KNo values that have at least one row where TB = 301. Then join that to the main table, which eliminates the "bad" records. This one doesn't read as clean as the above answer, but may make a difference in performance.